# QGraphicsItemGroup.removeFromGroup -- child items not correctly reparented to Scene

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qgraphicsview

I'm trying to remove a QGraphicsItem from a QGraphicsItemGroup. When calling removeFromGroup, the item is removed (of course). However, it's then no longer visible in the Scene. I have to call Scene.addItem(item) in order for it to appear again. This is apparently something you shouldn't do (I'm given a warning for doing that). But I can't seem to find another workaround.

Here's a minimal example:

```
import sys 

from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.view = QGraphicsView()
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.view.setScene(self.scene)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.view)


def add_group(scene):
    group = QGraphicsItemGroup()
    text = QGraphicsTextItem()
    text.setPlainText("I'm visible")
    group.addToGroup(text)
    scene.addItem(group)

    # After this, text is no longer in group. However, it is no longer visible.
    group.removeFromGroup(text)
    assert not text in group.childItems()

    # But text is still in scene. 
    assert text.scene() == scene

    # this works (i.e. text becomes visible again). However, it also produces a 
    # warning: QGraphicsScene::addItem: item has already been added to this scene. 
    # The docs also advice against it.
    scene.addItem(text)

    # According to the docs, I thought this might work, but it gives me a TypeError.
    # text.setParentItem(0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    add_group(main.scene)
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Tips and hints are very welcome.

Comment: Try adding the text item to the scene before adding it to the group

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but (over here, at least) it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Try setting the item's position after removing from the group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The QGraphicsTextItem can never be parented to a scene, because it's parent must be a QGraphicsItem (which QGraphicsScene does not inherit).

When the QGraphicsTextItem is created, it's parent is `None`. Its parent is set to `group` when it is added to it (QGraphicsItemGroup is a subclass of QGraphicsItem), then set back to `None` when it's removed from `group`.

Calling `scene.addItem()` is actually a NO-OP. Qt checks whether `scene` is the same as `text.scene()`, and if it is, it prints the warning and returns without doing anything.

The fact that it seems to "work" in some circumstances, is just an artifact of python's garbage-collecting mechanism.

If your test is re-cast in a more realistic way, the QGraphicsTextItem remains visible after removal from the group:

```
import sys

from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.view = QGraphicsView(self)
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene(self.view)
        self.view.setScene(self.scene)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.view)
        self.group = QGraphicsItemGroup()
        self.text = QGraphicsTextItem()
        self.text.setPlainText("I'm visible")
        self.group.addToGroup(self.text)
        self.scene.addItem(self.group)
        self.group.removeFromGroup(self.text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `text` is deleted since you don't have any reference to it after you remove it from the group, try this:

```
...
text = QGraphicsTextItem()
scene.text = text #just to keep the reference, ideally should be self.text = text
...
```

Now you don need `scene.addItem(text)`